# Ruby Netbeans plugin can't install

Tags: ruby, plugins, netbeans, ide

Some plugins require plugin org.jruby.jruby to be installed.
The plugin named org.jruby.jruby is needed and not found.  The following plugin is affected:       Ruby Projects

Where is org.jruby.jruby? I select all.

Comment: We need to select the org-jruby-jruby.jar file in the unzipped folder when “Add Plugins..”.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

When you select your plugins from the unzipped folder, make very sure to change the "Files of Type" filter to "All", so that you can include the JRuby JAR

https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/ruby_on_rails_in_netbeans

Comment: @user3381781 Why didn't you accept this answer? It seems solving the problem.

Comment: the answers must get accepted as it really helped! Thanks Tony Cho

Comment: Fine. This is very old question but I need to accept this for anyone who read it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Ruby and Rails plugin from [here](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38549/ruby-and-rails)
2. Unzip the downloaded file
3. Open `NetBeans > tools > Plugins > Downloaded > Add Plugins..`
4. Go to downloaded location and make files filter to `All Files`
5. Select all files and setup, IDE will restart and work for you